# Wordpress plugin error

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, plugins, comments

I upgraded my plugins and now i have error on my site.
It shows this:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'schema' not found or invalid function name in /home/dojkimk/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 170
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

I dont't know which plug in cause this problem.
I am using this facebook plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/

Can you help me ?

Comment: Just to be clear - this is the Facebook plugin you are using? wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/

Comment: I'm using this fb plugin: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with that one. You should look to see if http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/ fulfills your needs though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Facebook Comment Plugin. After updating to the 2.0 version, even I am getting the same error. Just deactivate it for a while. You can always activate it when the author finds a fix for it.

Comment: i deactivate it, and i am still getting the error, just on my main page... 
check it http://dojki.mk/

Comment: Clearing Cache will do. Error not appearing for me.

Comment: Ok, i upgraded the plugin with new upgrade, now the error is gone.